# C++ external static pointer is null from any class but one

Tags: c++, pointers, nullpointerexception, header-files

I'm trying to make a game so I need some kind of external header file for all constants, static fields and such. It's just a header file without a class,so I can use all its fields from any class. But when I try to add static pointer fields to my header file something strange happens. If I try to set up those pointers with NEW CLASSNAME() from any class they work only in this class. From anywhere other then that class pointer stays Null.

I tryed to use not static pointer field and shared_ptr.
I need to have an external pointer field I can always get or reset with new, from anywhere.
(Don't think if this matters but the pointer is to my own class)

Comment: static variables in global scope are per translation unit. This means that classes in separate cpps that include the header will have a separate instance of the static variable.

Comment: If you want to share a global variable, it should be declared as `extern` in the header file, and then defined (without `static` or `extern`) in one cpp file. If you declare it as `static` in the header file then you will end up with separate variables in each cpp file. It seems this is what has happened to you.

Comment: I think you better to use "singleton pattern".

Comment: Please provide a [mre].